# MVC - Using Ajax to render partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have this markup in an MVC app.

```
<div id="ingredientlistdiv">
    <% Recipe recipe = (Recipe)Model; %>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("IngredientsListControl", recipe.Ingredients); %>
</div>

<div id="ingrediententrydiv" align="left">
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add Ingredient", "Recipes/UpdateStep2", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ingredientlistdiv" }))
       { %>
    <p>
        <label for="Units">Units:</label><br />
        <%= Html.TextBox("Units", 0)%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Units", "*")%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Measure">Measure:</label><br />
        <%= Html.TextBox("Measure")%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Measure", "*")%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="IngredientName">Ingredient Name:</label><br />
        <%= Html.TextBox("IngredientName")%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("IngredientName", "*")%>
    </p>
    <p><a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">Save Ingredient</a></p>
    <%= Html.Hidden("RecipeID", recipe.RecipeID.ToString())%>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

When this runs the IngredientsListControl.ascx displayas a new page
in the browser and does not update the ingredientlistdiv.

This is my controller action

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult UpdateStep2(FormCollection form)
        {
            var factory = SessionFactoryCreator.Create();

            using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
            {
                Recipe recipe = GetRecipe(session, Convert.ToInt32(form["RecipeID"]));

                Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();

                ingredient.UpdateFromForm(form);
                ingredient.Validate(ViewData);

                if (ViewData.ModelState.Count == 0)
                {
                    recipe.Ingredients.Add(ingredient);
                    session.Save(recipe);
                    return PartialView("IngredientsListControl", recipe.Ingredients);
                }


                return Content("Error");
            }
        }
```

Am I doing the right thing on this line?

```
return PartialView("IngredientsListControl", recipe.Ingredients);
```

Is that how I render the control into the div so it does
not load new page.???

Malcolm

Comment: We've always used the full, app-relative path for the partial name, e.g. Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/ModuleNewUser.ascx")

Comment: Is it displaying the partial as a new page? Or some other page? What is the contents of your partial?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use this:

```
<a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">
```

...you should be aware that it's not the same as

```
<input type="submit" />
```

It doesn't raise the onsubmit event, and MVC's AJAX eventhandler is not called.

To confirm this is the issue, add

```
<input type="submit" />
```

inside the form and try it out.

Finally, just call onsubmit() from your link

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].onsubmit()">
```

Comment: However, I strongly suggest you to use the standard submit button (<input type="submit" />, Html.SubmitButton MVC helper). You will run into lots of trouble if you submit forms with <a href...>/JS - it's very hard to make it work in ALL browsers. You can change the appearance of the submit button with css styles, and it works 100% in all scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Might be worth ensuring that you have correctly referenced the ajaxmvc and jquery scripts in your page (master page). If these are incorrect a new page will be displayed instead of the correct output in the target div.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted to say. Can't find other reasons just looking at it. :)

Answer (score -2):

RenderPartial takes an action name, not the name of the user control, so replace "IngredientsListControl" with "UpdateStep2", your action name.

Comment: Sorry, but I`m quite sure it does not. That is what RenderAction does which is included in MvcFutures.