# VB Syntax to declare a single model in MVC (to leverage strongly typed views)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, strongly-typed-view

I'm trying to avoid the use of magic strings as much as I can, but I can't find the correct syntax for VB to bind a single model like is shown in this [c# example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750543/mvc-using-ajax-to-render-partial-view).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

(currently the below says "expected end of statement" under the Model text)

```
<% Dim FormObject As Form = (Form)Model %>
```

EDIT:

A simple directcast was need (sorry for the dumb question)

```
<%  Dim FormObject As Form = DirectCast(Model, Form)%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to port is a cast operator.  Try the following code.

```
<% Dim FormObject As Form = DirectCast(Model, Form) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to make your view strongly typed like this either you use C# or VB.NET:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<FormObject>" %>
```

so that when you want to use it you don't need to cast it

```
<% Dim FormObject As Form = Model %>
```