# ASP.NET MVC render partial from the POST method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

### Problem

I have Telerik TabControl and each tab content is a partial view. Everything works smoothly when request is GET:

```
//
// GET: /ProductVersion/Translations        
public ActionResult Translations(Guid id)
{
    VersionEditTabViewModel model = CreateTranslationsViewModel(id);
    return PartialView("Translations", model);
}
```

Now the problem is that on some tabs I have a Form that has controls that trigger submit event.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Translations(Guid id)
{
    FormCollection formCollection = new FormCollection(Request.Form);
    string message = string.Empty;
    int languageId = int.Parse(formCollection["TranslationsLanguageList"]);
    string action = formCollection["TranslationAction"];
    if(action == Constants.translation_save)
    {
        _translationModel.SaveTranslations(formCollection);
        message = "Translation information saved";
    }
    else if (action == Constants.translation_language_changed)
    {
/*
    PROBLEM: causes whole page to render, not partial
*/
        return PartialView("Translations", model);
    }
    return RedirectToAction( ... updates the complete page not only partial ...);
}
```

My question is: how to render partial from the POST method? Because now with that source code tab content will be loaded to the WHOLE page, not inside tab.

### Solution

I had to put DIV outside of the Ajax.Form and also I had incorrect submit on my DropDownList. What I did was that I created hidden submit button with Id and then I used jQuery to execute it's click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For additional reference, please refer to this question on SO:

[MVC - Using Ajax to render partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750543/mvc-using-ajax-to-render-partial-view)

This shows a complete implementation of the Ajax.BeginForm with surrounding DIV and inner form controls. You should be able to place this entire setup (DIV + Form + HTML Form Elements) in the Telerik Tab, like this:

```
<% Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
        .Name("TabStrip")
        .Items(tabstrip =>
        {
            tabstrip.Add()
                    .Text("Your Tab Text")
                    .Content(() =>
                    {%>
                        <div id="containerDiv" align="left">
                           <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Example", "Controller/Action", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "containerDiv" })){ %>
                           <%-- Render Partial here -->
                           <% } %>
                        </div>
                    <%});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I checked the link you posted. I made a little test and added a submit button instead of having only a DropDownList with submit added using jQuery. For some reason submit button behaves differently than DropDownList when submit is done. I have to investigate little bit more. I'll let you know when I solve it (finally)

Comment: I had other mistakes too like you pointed in the example. Div must be outside of the Ajax.BeginForm. Big thanks to Todd!

Answer (score 1):

I did my trough ajax form:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("*ActionName*", new { *parameter = ID* }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = (*div i will update*), OnSuccess = "*JavaScript that executes on success*", OnComplete = "s*ame as on success*", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
```

and then i have

```
return PartialView("*PartialViewName*", model);
```

in post Action

And it works just fine, on post, action returns partial view and then ajax form replaces the content of the div specified in the UpdateTargetId with InsertionMode.Replace

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't get working yet. This is what I added:

<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Translations", new { Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "translationContent", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })) 
   { %>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="translationContent">

... blaa blaa content blaa ..

</div>
<% } %>

On the controller side I have:

return PartialView("Translations", model);

Comment: It's still changing the whole content of the page

Comment: my update target id is a div wrapping the whole form and i got it like this

<div id="content">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView",model);
</div>

then when i do post, return is a partial view, so you need to replace the old rendered partial  view with the new one :D