# ASP.NET MVC 2 Ajax Site Master

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I started with a "new ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application" template and created a few controllers. I want the links on my navigation menu (located in Site.Master) to load my 'content' div (which has all of the controller output) via AJAX and not perform an entire page refresh.

I return PartialView() from TestController Index() method but this did not work. How should my navigation bar link be formatted (as an ActionLink()?) and what should my controller Index return? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why didn't it work?  How is it failing?  Maybe you could put up some code for everyone to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750543/mvc-using-ajax-to-render-partial-view) on Stackoverlow